# Very Slow Magento MySQL Query - MySQL eav_entity_store select

Tags: database, checkout, onepage-checkout, query

Hi guys I have showing in new relic a VERY slow query on /checkout/onepage/success/ on multiple store views on my Magento installation.

It is taking 57 seconds!

```
SELECT `eav_entity_store`.* FROM `eav_entity_store` WHERE (entity_type_id = :entity_type_id) AND (store_id = :store_id) FOR UPDATE
```

We have around 30 store views but does anyone have any idea why this specific query would take so long? The table is fairly small so I am stumped!

Thanks!

Comment: I've run into the same issue under heavy load, with lots of active users in checkout—we put our site in maintenance mode, then cleared all caches and restarted all the servers... and things worked again for a while. But the query started blocking things again and we had to do the same process a couple times.